# Mount additional routes in Rails specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I want to test 3rd party sites embedding a javascript widget (provided by my Rails app) and submitting forms to an endpoint in my rails app.

To do this, I have created a dummy sinatra app that I test with Capybara:

```
# spec/system/widget_spec.rb

require 'sinatra/base'
class DummyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/form' do
    @widget_code = params[:widget_code]
    erb :form
  end
end

require 'rails_helper'

...
```

I'm defining this app *before* Rails is loaded in my spec, so that I can do the following in `routes.rb`:

```
mount DummyApp => '/dummy' if defined? DummyApp
```

This works if I run just this one spec, but if I run the whole suite, Rails is loaded before my DummyApp is defined.

Ideally I'd like to pull this line out of `routes.rb` entirely and allow my test to inject custom routes, so my routes file isn't cluttered with test-related routes.

1) Is there a way to tinker with rails routes within tests?

2) If not, what's the best way to go about testing this type of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a helper `with_routing` you could use [(docs)](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions/with_routing):

```
with_routing do |set|
  set.draw do
    mount DummyApp => '/dummy'
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: That's cool, I hadn't seen this API before. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for an entire example group, just inside a single spec. However, this does give me the pieces I need to do it myself I think. Thanks!

Comment: @BenScheirman maybe you could try with an [around](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/hooks/around-hooks) hook? Similar to the resque example [here](http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/using-abusing-rspec-metadata.html)